# Google Sheets errors on a REGEX statement

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a regex expression that does exactly what I need it to do, but GoogleSheets REGEXEXTRACT shows it as an error.  Any ideas?

Cell I2 contains the text:  "Status 9/27 Pass Rate: 92.9%"

Formula in Cell I3: =REGEXEXTRACT(I2,"[^: ]+(?=%)")

Error in Cell I3 is: "Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "[^: ]+(?=%)" is not a valid regular expression."

Cell I3 should contain "92.9"

-Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Spreadsheet regex functions, and `REGEXEXTRACT` thus, too, uses RE2 regex engine that does not support any lookarounds.

Use a capturing group instead:

```
([^: ]+)%
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0WbGZ1/1). Here, `([^: ]+)` captures any 1+ chars other than `:` and space into Group 1 and that value will be returned by `REGEXEXTRACT` function, but only if `%` follows that pattern immediately.

[image]

Another regex you may use is

```
(\d*\.?\d+)%
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0WbGZ1/2)

The `\d*\.?\d+` pattern matches 0+ digits, an optional `.` and then 1+ digits. If you do not expect `.8` like numbers, use `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%` pattern.

Comment: Thank you!  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex, but slightly shorter, returns a Number (the `*1`) and for some may be easier to understand:

```
=left(right(I2,5),4)*1
```